# Can the ring which attaches the Nikon D700 strap to the camera be replaced?

Tags: camera-straps, nikon-d700

I bought a used D700, and when I tried to attach the camera strap I realized it's impossible, as the camera was missing the small triangular iron loops (see the image from my D300). Are these parts available anywhere? I wouldn't even know how to search for them...

[image]

Comment: Because this is a photography site, I feel justified in pedantically pointing out that _that's not a screenshot_. :)

Comment: harsh but true :-)

Comment: @mattdm I anticipate somebody editing my edit :-)

Comment: Chris 1. What they said. 2. You could also get someone to make you a visually similar one if you value the look. If using a split  ring or custom version be sure it will take the loading forces and not pull open. The D700 ring has 2 full turns. You could possibly get 3 in there and still have enough freedom of movement if wanted. 3. If you want a quick temporary fix that needs to be treated with intelligence you could make one with a paperclip and pliers. The metal would be adequately strong but you'd need to ensure the result was secure against "unravelling".

Comment: An alternative would be to use something like the 'r-strap' which doesnt attach to these points but rather to the tripod mount instead :)

Comment: Although straps that attach to the tripod mount are quite popular, neither Canon nor Nikon will go on record as saying they are engineered to support the weight of the camera plus a moderately heavy lens *pulling* (which requires *tensile strength*) on the mount while in motion (and exerting a heavier g-load during acceleration and deceleration) instead of *resting* (which only requires *compressive strength* at 1g) on it when attached to a static tripod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with any OEM Nikon parts is that you have to be a Nikon Service Center to get them. Nikon no longer ships replacement parts to dealers or camera repair shops.

In your case, that isn't as terrible as it may sound. The parts you are looking for are generally called split rings. On most cameras they are round. A few camera straps, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H7GFXM), come with round split rings attached.

A while back Fuji used some similar triangular rings that caused excessive wear to the lugs on the X100 and X-Pro1. Once the lugs break off the entire back on the Fuji models must be replaced. It is also possible the lugs were made out of too soft of a material. [Link](http://www.fujix-forum.com/index.php/topic/4873-fujifilm-triangle-rings-causes-lug-wear/)

My suggestion would be to go to a sporting goods store that caters to fishing lure builders, as split rings of various sizes are used for building certain types of lures. They usually also sell some specialized pliers to open them when installing and removing them.

Comment: Split rings can also be found in sailing shops, as they are used on sailboats a lot.