# What is the name of the part that goes between a camera strap and eyelet?

Tags: terminology, camera-straps

**What is the name of the part that goes between a camera strap and eyelet?**

Sometimes camera-straps fits directly onto an eyelet which is fixed on the camera body. On some cameras though, there is a small part which goes between the two.

It looks like a small triangular or rectangular paper-clip. See the image below for the triangular version. In this example, there is also a plastic frame which shows as two triangular edges right next to the eyelets. I'm missing one on a camera and don't know what its call to look for a replacement.

[image: Nikon Df]

Comment: *Split Ring(s)*

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38419/can-the-ring-which-attaches-the-nikon-d700-strap-to-the-camera-be-replaced/38422#38422

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45784/15871

Comment: @MichaelClark - Thanks! Even if those two posts used the right term I would not have know to search for it. As you can see from the photo, the Nikon's are there, it's a Fuji that's missing them.

Comment: I agree with Itai, I don't think this is a duplicate, though they're clearly related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a split ring, often used for keys, but these are much smaller and triangular. The little plastic bit seems to keep it from rotating, but if you had a circular one it wouldn't be a problem. Normal split rings can be found at WalMart or a hardware store, though maybe not small enough. Something like this might be found in an arts and crafts store.

Comment: To add to this, the triangular shape is likely to make sure there's even tension across the camera strap where it supports the split ring. A circular one (with a small diameter) would put a lot of tension on the sides of the strap, squashing and potentially tearing it. The flat bar of the triangle means it's (generally) evenly spread across the section of the strap. So if you can only find a circular replacement, make sure its not too small (in both wire diameter and ring diameter), and watch for fraying of the strap itself.

Comment: I was looking for a tie-breaking between the two answers and I think the tidbit about the plastic to avoid rotation does it :)

Answer (score 4):

These are split rings and can be found in a few places in this format... For example:

[Amazon - Hama Split Rings](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hama-00027902-Split-Rings/dp/B00006JCX6)

or

[EBay (claimed) genuine Nikon set](http://www.ebay.com/itm/genuine-set-of-NIKON-Japan-STRAP-LUGS-RINGS-fits-all-Nikon-DSLR-SLR-/221377142690).